# Node.JS - Speak Query Result via Alexa

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, variables, alexa-skills-kit

I'm very new to coding and I've hit a brick wall here. I'm using the mysql module for node.js, and I'd like to execute a query for use in my Alexa skill. The idea is that Alexa will speak the result of my query. How can I place the query result in a variable, and then reference that variable in my "tell" command for Alexa?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
'LaunchRequest': function () {

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'myserver.amazonaws.com',
  user     : 'secret',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'mydata',
  port     : '1433'
});

connection.query('SELECT `book` FROM `dbo.tblBibleBooks` WHERE `id` = "4"', function (error, results, fields) {

 });


  connection.end();
 this.emit(':tell', myvariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`How can I place the query result in a variable` this is quite close:

```
connection.query('SELECT `book` FROM `dbo.tblBibleBooks` WHERE `id` = "4"', 
function (error, results, fields) {
  this.emit(':tell', results);
});
```

that's it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I place the query result in a variable, and then reference
>   that variable in my "tell" command for Alexa?

#### The old way - binding the callback

You can bind the context of `this` to the callback function, so that the result can be directed to the `.emit` function. To do that, use `function.bind` in order to set the `this` context within a callback:

```
connection.query('SELECT `book` FROM `dbo.tblBibleBooks` WHERE `id` = "4"', function (error, results, fields) {
  // handle if error or no result...
  this.emit(':tell', results);
}.bind(this));
```

#### The new way - use an arrow function

If you are capable of using ES6, you can use an arrow function. It allows you to use `this` inside the function but reference to the context outside the funciton (it has no own `this`context):

```
connection.query('SELECT `book` FROM `dbo.tblBibleBooks` WHERE `id` = "4"', (error, results, fields) => {
  // handle if error or no result...
  this.emit(':tell', results);
});
```

#### Readings / references

Read more on callbacks here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Read more on `bind` here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Read more arrow functions here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Read more on ES6 here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla